# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'context'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My goal is to make an API request when user types something on input. I'm getting the data successfully. However the component is rerendering twice and giving me this warning. If I include 'context' I'm getting an infinite loop. Here's my code:

**Component.js:**

```
const SearchBox = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const { handleSearch, searchResults } = useContext(MovieContext);

  console.log(searchResults);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      handleSearch(searchTerm);
    }, 500);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [searchTerm]);

  const renderResults = () => {
    if (searchResults.length > 0) {
      searchResults.map(result => {
        return (
          <div key={result.Title}>
            <img src={result.Poster} alt={result.Title} />;
          </div>
        );
      });
    }
    return;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <label>
        <b>Search</b>
      </label>
      <input
        className="input"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={e => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div className="dropdown is-active">
        <div className="dropdown-menu">
          <div className="dropdown-content results">{renderResults()}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

On top of this context.searchResults is undefined, although I set the initial value as an empty array. I wanted to know what causing this. What am I doing wrong? Here is my context code below:

**Context.js:**

```
const Context = React.createContext("");

export class MovieStore extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [],
      handleSearch: this.handleSearch
    };
  }

  handleSearch = async term => {
    try {
      if (term !== "") {
        const response = await axios.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/", {
          params: {
            apikey: apikey,
            s: term
          }
        });
        this.setState({ searchResults: response.data.Search });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same thing about an infinite loop is mentioned in `React` docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats). So the cause of infinite loop is that, in context render function, you create **new** value **every** time render is called.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider
        // ! value object creates every time render is called - it's bad
        value={{ ...this.state, handleSearch: this.handleSearch }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
```

It causes every consumer to rerender when context state updates. So, if you put `context` in dependencies array of `useEffect`, eventually, it'll cause an infinite loop, because `context` value is always different. Here's what happens:

1. Context makes a search query.
2. Context state updates with the new data, which causes all consumers to rerender.
3. In context consumer `useEffect` sees that context value has been
   updated and it calls `setTimeout` which will call for another search
   in context provider in 500ms.
4. Consumer calls context to make another search query and we've got an infinite loop!

The solution is to keep context value the same object, while only updating its properties. It can be done by putting all the necessary properties inside of context state. Like that:

```
export class MovieStore extends Component {
  handleSearch = async term => {
    try {
      if (term !== "") {
        const response = await axios.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/", {
          params: {
            apikey: "15bfc1e3",
            s: term
          }
        });
        this.setState({ searchResults: response.data.Search });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  state = {
    searchResults: [],
    handleSearch: this.handleSearch // <~ put method directly to the state
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={this.state}> // <~ Just returning state here
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps <3

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your solution by putting the method directly to the context state. If I declare the state up top, I get undefined  for handleSearch function. If I put it below the function, it seems to be working. However I'm still getting an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you replace your code in a question with new the code, so I can assess what it wrong